# Android - Canvas.clipRect() - Removing existing clip

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I have a `Canvas` object, at some point I set a clip so I could draw into that 'window/section' without worrying about overflow into other parts of the canvas.

After I'm done drawing into the 'window' I want to remove that clip area, which I cant seem to do.

There is no remove clip function, when I try to apply a new clip on the entire canvas, that clip is not being applied - Calling `canvas.getClipBounds()` right after applying the new clip returns a `Rect` with the previous clip.

Comment: how do u apply the new clip `on the entire canvas`?

Comment: I've tried something like canvas.setClip(0,0,viewWidth,viewHeight) and also in local coordinates of the applied clip, if left is 8, so the new left would be -8, both didnt work.

Comment: `setClip` or `clipRect`?

Comment: you must use 'clipRect (Rect rect, Region.Op op)' with op Union so it´ll add. It´s croping more and more until you specify the add operation. It´s kind of a boolean intersect. set the union with all the surface. Also you can `canvas.save()` before croping, crop, draw, and restore to have full clip bounds again

Comment: BTW, notice the javadoc for clipRect specifies the clip will apply to the current clip so it´s an AND operation, intersecting both paths

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `canvas.save()` before setting the clip rect then `canvas.restore()` to discard the clipping rect.

Comment: A typically stupid API from Google. The docs about "save" - Saves the current matrix and clip onto a private stack. - Then try naming your API as SaveMatrixAndClippingSettings Google.

Answer (score 0):

you must use 'clipRect (Rect rect, Region.Op op)' with op Union so it´ll add. It´s croping more and more until you specify the add operation. It´s kind of a boolean intersect. set the union with all the surface. Also you can canvas.save() before croping, crop, draw, and restore to have full clip bounds again.

BTW, notice the javadoc for clipRect specifies the clip will apply to the current clip so it´s an AND operation, intersecting both paths

Comment: I'm getting an error saying its not allowed to use Union - so this is not really a valid answer anymore. The answer below does the job and works very well.